# javascript to show other page in dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-dialog

i have a situation here
i just wrote a code for a grid

```
function openDialogLog(id) {
        var $dialog = $('#DialogLog')
            .html('<iframe style="border: 0px;" src="viewuserlog.aspx?id=' + id + '" width="100%" height="100%" style="left:250px;width:900px;"></iframe>')
            .dialog({
                title: "User Log",
                autoOpen: false,
                dialogClass: 'dialog_fixed,ui-widget-header',
                modal: true,
                height: 500,
                width: 900,
                left: 250,
                minWidth: 400,
                minHeight: 400,
                draggable: true,
                close: function () {
                    $(this).append(history.go(0));

                }
            });
            $dialog.dialog('open'); 
    }
```

now the situation is that when i close log and open other user page just postbacks and then it shows a dialog

kindly help me to solve the problem

Comment: `$(this).append(history.go(0));` doesn't make much sense, what are you trying to accomplish on close action?

Comment: when i did not put  $(this).append(history.go(0)); the button which calls this opendialoglog(id) was working in odd clicks and page does some postbacks on even clicks
like when i click for the first time it works flawlessly
and on second click just a post back
on third works
forth does some postback
and so on....

Comment: i am fetching a grid from database and populating on grid and put a button on grid to view full log which is on viewuserlog.aspx so i am passing userid as querystring

Comment: `history.go(0)` refreshes the page and return no value, so `$(this).append()` will not affect anything

Comment: ok forget that close :function() w/o that close function when i m closing box every thing is ok but for 2nd time i am opening that by grid button i found that its does some postback and nothing happens and after that when i click for the 3rd time it shows desired user's log... now my point is i dont want client to click twice for the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

after much googling i have found the solution.. replace `$(this).append(history.go(0));` with `$(this).dialog('destroy');` thanks